# I want to access a public method from one script to another in Unity. I have tried the below code

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I am getting the below error while accessing `ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet();` in `Player.cs` from  public `GameObject GetBulltet ()` which is in `ObjectPoolingManager.cs`

```
Assets\SPF_Assets\Scripts\Game\Player.cs(4,7): error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'ObjectPoolingManager' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead
```

**Player.cs Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using ObjectPoolingManager; //Tried this, didnt work

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet();

            GameObject bulletObject = Instantiate (bulletPrefab);
            bulletObject.transform.position = playerCamera.transform.position + playerCamera.transform.forward;
            bulletObject.transform.forward = playerCamera.transform.forward;
        }
    }
}
```

**ObjectPoolingManager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPoolingManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static ObjectPoolingManager instance;
    public static ObjectPoolingManager Instance { get { return instance; } }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake () {
        instance = this;
    }

    public GameObject GetBulltet () {
        Debug.Log ("Hell0");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove this line `using ObjectPoolingManager; //Tried this, didnt work`

Comment: Tried that as well, doesn't work. commented that.

Comment: If the line is really removed, the error message should be changed at least, since the 4th line of Player.cs is empty now.

Comment: I deleted that line and now its this: Assets\SPF_Assets\Scripts\Game\Player.cs(12,43): error CS1061: 'ObjectPoolingManager' does not contain a definition for 'GetBullet' and no accessible extension method 'GetBullet' accepting a first argument of type 'ObjectPoolingManager'

Comment: I think this is a typo, because the method name is GetBull***t***et

Comment: Oh yesss...It worked. Dam I feel so sorry to trouble you for a silly thing. But Thank you very much for helping me out Shingo.

Comment: you dont wanna give your comment as answer bro ?

Comment: No, I suggest you to remove this question, because it's a *a simple typographical error* which is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on the site.

Comment: Oh got it, Thanks a lot for the advice once again.

Answer (score 1):

I re-read the code multiple times and finally realised your answer is right in your question already:

```
I am getting the below error while accessing
ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet(); in Player.cs
from public GameObject GetBulltet () which is in ObjectPoolingManager.cs
```

I verified this in your code and you actually call a function `ObjectPoolingManager.Instance.GetBullet()` even though there is no such function but instead `GetBulltet()` which should have been `GetBullet()` instead.